# JQuery wrap span around text on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a little menu from which I load `html`-files into a div on click.
I want menu items to be wrapped in a span (or div) when clicked upon so I can control the style. If another menu item is clicked the span should disappear and be put around the other clicked menu item.

I'm pretty lost on this and I'm not quite sure on how to approach this other than in below snippet. Also the text that has to be wrapped in a `<span>` could differ.

Please see snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#om').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/tekst.shtml');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#resul').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/resul.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#billeder').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/billeder.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#video').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/video.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#afkom').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/afkom.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#presse').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/presse.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.hesteundertop a', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active a {
  background: green;
  width: auto;
  color: grey;
}

.hesteundertop a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E181A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hesteundertop a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E181A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hesteundertop a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hesteundertop a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hesteundertop">
  <p><a id="om" href="#">Om Corona</a> &#124; <a id="resul" href="#">Resultater</a> &#124; <a id="billeder" href="#">Billeder</a> &#124; <a id="video" href="#">Video</a> &#124; <a id="afkom" href="#">Afkom</a> &#124; <a id="presse" href="#">Presse</a></p>
</div>
<div class="hestetekst">
  <!--#include virtual="html/tekst.shtml"--><br />
  <hr class="hr75" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use `.wrap()` and `.unWrap()`

Comment: Are you sure you need to wrap it? Can't you just add a class to the element itself?

Comment: Don't wrap it, just use the `.parent()` then add/remove classes.

Comment: @Barmer Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Fred Can you please provide an example? I'm note familiar with the `.parent()`

Comment: @SimonJensen `.parent()' just traverses the element to its parent element in the DOM tree. So capture the onclick event, then call the `.parent()` on the element, then remove a class from all siblings, while adding a new class.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j03fqhdy/

Comment: @Fred Thank you. Nice approach. I have updated my snippet. i made the `.active`-class target the `a` otherwise the entire line would have been colored. Yet it targets all instances of anchored text instead of only what have been clicked upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do  [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
  $('.hesteundertop .active a').unwrap(  )
  $(this).wrap("<span class='active'></span>");
```

Above code will wrap clicked link with span and unwrap it.

I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#om').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/tekst.shtml');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#resul').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/resul.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#billeder').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/billeder.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#video').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/video.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#afkom').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/afkom.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#presse').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('html/presse.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.hesteundertop a', function(e) {
  $('.hesteundertop .active a').unwrap(  )
  $(this).wrap("<span class='active'></span>");
  
});
```

```css
.active a {
  background: green;
  width: auto;
  color: grey;
}

.hesteundertop a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E181A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hesteundertop a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2E181A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hesteundertop a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hesteundertop a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hesteundertop">
  <p><a id="om" href="#">Om Corona</a> &#124; <a id="resul" href="#">Resultater</a> &#124; <a id="billeder" href="#">Billeder</a> &#124; <a id="video" href="#">Video</a> &#124; <a id="afkom" href="#">Afkom</a> &#124; <a id="presse" href="#">Presse</a></p>
</div>
<div class="hestetekst">
  <!--#include virtual="html/tekst.shtml"--><br />
  <hr class="hr75" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear `active` from all elements at once and then add it to current item.

```
$('.hesteundertop a').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.hesteundertop a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kidkie/pen/VGPQzO)

Comment: This works like a charm. But do you know why it is unable to "hold" some css styles such as `text-decoration: underline;`, `color: #somecolor;` etc?

Comment: Doesn't it work when you put the CSS on the .active class?